# Blocking auto-reply to HTTPS request

Tags: javascript, express, http, https, axios

I'm building an application with nw.JS, and I made a working login screen for it, that communicates with the server via HTTPS requests. Basically, I'm sending out a request to the server that contains the username and password input, the server checks if the username and password matches on a MYSQL database, then sends back a response containing a boolean value, depending if the username password combination matches.

Now the issue is that with a program called "HTTP Debugger" (probably can be done with Wireshark and other apps as well) I can see the decrypted HTTPS requests, and I can auto-reply to them, manipulating the outcome on the client side, so the user can pass the log-in screen even if the username password does not match.

**Client side code (using axios):**

```
  axios.post('https://example.com:8443/auth', {
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    if(response.data) {
      // If the username password matches
    }
    else {
      // If the username password does not match
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

**Server side (using express.js and the built in https node library):**

```
app.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;

  if(username && password) {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "'", function (err, result) {
      if(err) return console.log(err);
      if(result[0] == undefined) return res.send(false);

      verify(password, result[0].password).then(result => {
        res.send(result);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Is there a way to bypass this, or block auto-replys? I thought about "encrypting" the boolean value with the node crypto library, but that just sounds wrong. Thank you for the answer in advance!

Comment: Acually there is no way to sniff login details by wireshark by some third person if you allready estabilished tls connection (https). I dont know http debugger but isnt it some browser plugin? (like browser console - which displays allready decrypted requests) Btw bevare of the sql injection - its the most dangerous thing on the code example.

Comment: Don't know much about HTTP Debugger, it is a desktop application, and I can auto-reply to my own HTTPS requests, that is all really. And also, thanks for the heads up, tryna learn my way around MYSQL and requests in general, but this kinda left me hanging, and I don't really want to ship even a little application where users (even if a very little number of them) can abuse such thing.

Comment: Than i believe it probably create some http server and listen on 443 port + maybe do some dns override. Or it might do man in the middle techique as a proxy. (but dont know the tool) If you try direct communication with foreign host and analyze tcp dump in wireshark, you wont be able to read auth info. But there are plenty techniques to improve safety like certificates, HTST etc.

Comment: Btw is not bad idea to do some camouflage - like base64 encode credentials, replace username+password with one letter parameter and dont forget to protect from frequent auth tryouts

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What do you mean by certificates exactly? I have a HTTPS certificate and key I'm using for the connection itself. I'm guessing thats not what you meant. This is quite an early project, and I'll definetly take your tips and improve the whole thing based on them, I just wanted to figure out a way around this auto-reply stuff really, it's kinda fustrating. This video kinda sums up what my issue really is (not my video, this is how I found out that this auto-reply thing is possible though): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wmQBHylKGw